# Mongo Collection or Document

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm looking at the possibility of switching from Filemaker to a MERN app. I get the basic idea of NoSQL databases but its a very different way of thinking. I have recreated what I need in MySQL, but Mongo DB (or Firestore) interests me.

The app is used to record workouts of clients. Each person has many workouts, each workout has many items within it. I'm not sure the best way to do this in Mongo.

I'm between using a collection for all workouts, and each workout has an array of all the items (exercises) they did. Or have the items as a separate collection with a workout_ID to link them up.

Probably the most important thing I'm looking for here is the ability to see all the instances someone did an exercise. From my understanding, if I do it the first way, every single record will be pulled. But the second would only return the documents in that collection that would match exercise_ID and person_ID.

Which is the best approach for such a project?

Answer (score 0):

The second option is the best way to store the data in your case. You can always separate the items in a different collection and store the item Ids in your main collection i.e workouts here.

If you are concerned about querying(joins) them, mongoose provide 'populate' to fetch data between multiple collections using ids as references.

Or you can also use aggregate queries to achieve the same.

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option for me would be having an array of the items inside each workout, because that's basically the purpose of using no-SQL databases, to access faster to the data.
However there's a basic rule.. if you think the array of items of each workout it's gonna grow very fast and it will get so big.. then it's better to have a separate collection for the items. if it's not.. then keep those inside an array.

Hope this can be helpful to you.. greetings! :)